# Installling PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

i'm having real trouble installing php8.1 on Ubuntu 22.10.
I did this :

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

When i execute the command:

```
sudo apt install php8.1 -y
```

I get :

> E: Unable to locate package php8.1

> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1'

which i dont understand,because when i visit the repo http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu i see php8.1 files there(http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.1/).
I tried removing and adding the andrej repo but still it didnt work.
What is wrong?Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a search in the [package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php), you don't need to add any additional repositories to install `php 8.1` on `Ubuntu 22.10`.

Therefore, you should be able to install `php 8.1` by using the following command.

```
sudo apt install php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Even though it tells me: 'the version php is already the newest version (2:8.0+82~0build1)'.I would need PHP8.1.

Comment: So i guess you are using `Ubuntu 21.10` instead of `Ubuntu 22.10`?

Comment: your guess is correct.I did update yesterday,but i didnt change release.I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: So in that case, your intended way seems correct. I assume you have `software-properties-common` installed and `add-apt-repository` successfully added the repository.